# How can we add dropdown in KnpMenu in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, knpmenu

I am already having a menu built using KnpMenu in Symfony project. But, it is having just four childs meas four menu items. Now, I have to add dropdown. If anyone has any idea, please, comment. Please, help how to get its dropdown css, dropdown classses, how to customize it.

Reference - https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Gregoire-M/4585334 maybe this is what you want, or this one https://gist.github.com/Invis1ble/503db8bb9ff6dafc52c8b2bf7c6fec42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropdown can be added by adding child too the menu items in php file and for formatting use own class or bootstrap class.